# How to determine the values of integer matrices?

Tags: matrices, integers, integer-lattices

If $A \times W=F$, where $A$ is $2 \times 2$ integer matrix, $W$ is $2 \times 4$ integer matrix and $F$ is $2 \times 4$ integer matrix.

If I know the value of $F$ ($2 \times 4$ integer matrix), i.e.,
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 &1\\
0 & -1 & -1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}

How can I determine the value of matrices $A$ and $W$?

Subject to:

1. In $W$ matrix, the values of elements $w13, w14, w21, w22$ = zero, and the values of $w11, w12, w23, w24 \neq 0$ must be integers and not equal zeros. i.e.,
   \begin{bmatrix}
   w11 & w12 & 0 &0\\
   0 & 0 & w23 & w24
   \end{bmatrix}
2. All elements of the $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$ are integers and the rank of $A$ must be 2.

Comment: $A$ and $W$ are not uniquely determined by $F$.  As a trivial example, if $F$ is all zeros, then it could be that $W$ is all zeros and $A$ is anything at all.

Comment: I try to limit the search direction, what if I add additional constraints as:
$w11, w12, w23, w24 \neq 0$ are integers and not equal to zeros.  Also, the rank of matrix $A$ must be 2.

Comment: That $A$ is rank 2 is implied, since $F$ is rank $2$. As given, I don’t believe there are any solutions. Any system with a solution with $W$ as described would have to have $F$’s last first two columns be multiples of each other (and same for the last two).

Comment: You've already given some form to $W$, so do the same for $A=\left(\begin{array}{cc} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22}\end{array}\right)$ and you should very quickly get to $a_{12}w_{23}=0, a_{12}w_{24}=1$, implying $w_{23}=0$ which you said is not true.

Comment: Maybe it's better to give us some insight into what you're working on. Are you trying to find what matrices $F$ yield unique pairs of solutions $A, W$, or maybe just solutions? Or maybe, given certain matrices $F$, there is a unique $A$ given certain conditions on $W$ and you're trying to find those conditions?

Comment: @PepeSilvia Yes, given certain matrices F, there is a unique A given certain conditions on W and I am trying to find those conditions

Comment: What are the conditions on the matrix F?

Comment: For any solution pair $A,W$ given $F$, $-A,-W$ is also a solution so you'll never quite have uniqueness.

Comment: I don't need to have a unique $A$ and $W$. Actually, any $A$ and $W$ satisfy the constraints are acceptable for me. @PepeSilvia

Answer (score 3):

With the given $F$, the equations to solve are
$$ \eqalign{
a_{{1,1}}w_{{1,1}}&=1\cr
a_{{1,1}}w_{{1,2}}&=1\cr
a_{{1,2}}w_{{2,3}}&=0\cr
a_{{1,2}}w_{{2,4}}&=1\cr
a_{{2,1}}w_{{1,1}}&=0\cr
a_{{2,1}}w_{{1,2}}&=-1\cr
a_{{2,2}}w_{{2,3}}&=-1\cr
a_{{2,2}}w_{{2,4}}&=1}$$
$w_{2,3} \ne 0$ from equation 7 and $a_{1,2} \ne 0$ from equation 4 so equation 3 is impossible.